# Unused forms/objects MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Is there any way I can identify unused forms/reports/queries in a compiled Access (2003) project?

---

Edit : There is no check for unused objects menu item in my database window.

[AccessContextMenu http://f.imagehost.org/0551/AcessContextMenu.jpg](http://f.imagehost.org/0551/AcessContextMenu.jpg)

Comment: See my reply to your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in the Database window, right click on the object (form/report/etc) and select "Object Dependencies". If it doesn't show up any where, it probably isn't used.

Although that doesn't tell you if it is called in VBA code somewhere. However you can almost totally eliminate that possibility by doing a search for the object name when viewing the VBA and make sure that you have "Current Project" selected instead of "Current Module". It doesn't prevent some evil coder from string concatenating the object name together somewhere; but it's unlikely.

Comment: It should be there, here's MS's page on how to get it back:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;833219

Comment: If it's a complied project, you won't be able to search the VBA code.

Comment: Compiled or exported to an MDE. It's not an MDE, because in the screen shot, the Design View option is not greyed out. Besides that, I just tried viewing the dependencies on an MDE and it worked. Viewing the code it self didn't but I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: Relying on objects dependencies is suicidal. On many Access apps I inherited during my missions, it could not even complete its initial scan without crashing.

Comment: @iDevlop In which case, you've probably got bigger problems (e.g., the MDB is corrupt in some forms/reports). Using that undocumented switch to force everything to recompile will probably show you what's broken (take a backup first of course).

Answer (score 0):

Try SpeedFerret over anything from fms (it has add'l features that will probably be useful to you as a developer, and it supports .mde files).

A demo can be obtained here:
http://www.moshannon.com/downloads.html

Other useful MSAccess utitlities:
http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/thirdparty.htm

Comment: SpeedFerret is dead, just like that link to it.